# How can I detect changes in a form inside an iframe from an Angular component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I would like to detect changes from a form that is inside an iframe, and I want to do that from an Angular component. The situation is better explained in this image:
[image]

For my case in particular, I would like to detect the first change only. But this might be useful to someone else to have a method to detect changes all the time.

My component HTML:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <iframe #iframe [src]="iframe.source">
</div>
```

Comment: The iframe has to emit an event in the first place (we don't know if it does), but even then, I'm not sure whether the event will be visible from the host page at all?

Comment: That is what I want to know. I thought about adding event listeners, but the scope of the callback functions is limited to the `iframe`. I wonder if the events can be propagated from `iframe` to the `window` element of the main page. I'm still clueless.

Comment: My guess is, the event will stay inside the iframe, since it's a sandbox. The very goal of an iframe is to encapsulate and isolate code execution.

Comment: Is the iFrame domain the same as the parent domain? If so then it can be done. If not - it still can be done if you have at least full control over both the iFrame as the parent code.

Comment: You have to do it manually, by emitting an event using postMessage from the iframe and then add a listener on PostMessage from your project to get the emitted event with values.